# Расположить по два квадрата в ряд с автоматическим переносом на новую строку

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как расположить по два полностью адаптивных квадрата в ряд с автоматическим переносом на новую строку?

```css
div {
height: 50vw; width: 50vw; float: left; margin: 10px; background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

div {
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  div {
    height: 50vw;
    width: 50vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  div {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать вот так: все блоки сделать `display: inline-block` и ширину в половину ширины контейнера (минус `3%` на отступы для блоков). Отступы можно сделать тоже в процентах (`1%` от ширины контейнера). И еще убрать `float: left`

Как-то так:

```css
div {
height: 50vw; 
width: 47%;
display: inline-block;
margin: 1%;
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```